# How to integrate meteor's velocity tests with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, meteor, meteor-velocity

On [Velocity's GH page](https://github.com/xolvio/velocity#benefits) it mentions "easy CI integration" as one of the benefits, but I haven't seen any documentation about it.

How can I integrate Velocity with Jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

> <s>meteor --test</s>
>
> meteor run --test

This does the same thing as the velocity-ci without the extra installation

Comment: Did you mean `meteor run --test`? This did the same as velocity-ci does, except that it doesn't exit with the status code, which is fundamental for ci. The process just stays up and running after running the tests.

`meteor --test` just booted my app normally.

Comment: oh, that' a bug! I'll post it up

Comment: Great, thanks! I think the best would be to have 2 modes: `meteor run --test` and `meteor run --test-single-run` (in lack of a better name)

Comment: On 0.9.4 the process stays up and running, but on 1.0 it ends with the correct status code.

Comment: Do you mean  you add `meteor run --test` as a Build Step in Jenkins, under `Execute Shell`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [velocity-ci](https://www.npmjs.org/package/velocity-ci)

> **velocity-cli**
>
> NPM module for running your velocity test suites from the command-line
>
> **Installation**
>
> npm install -g velocity-ci
>
> **Run**
>
> From inside your project directory type velocity
>
> **How it works**
>
> The velocity-cli spawns a meteor process and connects to it using DDP.
>   PhantomJS connects to the meteor process to trigger client side tests.
>   Test results received via DDP are printed at the console. This process
>   exits with the appropriate exit status code.

So the build step would be `velocity` inside the meteor directory

Comment: Hey, this is npm library deprecated

Comment: @sam hatoum I know but my amswer is old. the meteor team merged the cli into meteor as of version 1.0

Comment: Yep and thank you for answering in August :) I was just making sure nobody else would pick up this answer.