# Using Jenkins CI with Velocity for testing Meteor apps

Tags: meteor, jenkins, meteor-velocity

I have looked around for an answer but can't get this working. I have both my Meteor app and Jenkins running locally on OS X. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559613/how-to-integrate-meteors-velocity-tests-with-jenkins)

[image]

but the build fails with the following output

[image]

My lack of knowledge of both Jenkins and Meteor is clearly at fault here, but I can't find a solution online.

I had to use `/usr/local/bin/meteor` rather than just `meteor` because it seemed the Jenkins user could not find the meteor command. So maybe I am going wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Jenkins expert, but what I do in order to get access to the installed executables for the `jenkins` user is to call <strike>`!/bin/bash -l`</strike> `#!/bin/bash -l` at the beginning of the script. That way you would be able to call `meteor`.

I assume that when you run `meteor run --test` on your local machine it runs without problems, is that correct?

I would ssh into the Jenkins instance and check if there's another process using port 3001, as the error suggest. Maybe there a running meteor process?

Comment: the shebang is missing `#` but with that it works, thanks!